# #1067 - Invalid default value for 'remember_token'

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

In the Lynda tutorial "Up and Running with Laravel", a sample app (authapp) is created, allowing user to log in.

Here is the structure of the create_user migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($newtable)
        {
            $newtable->increments('id');
            $newtable->string('email')->unique();
            $newtable->string('username',100)->unique();
            $newtable->string('password',50);
            $newtable->string('remember_token',100);
            $newtable->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And here is the corresponding view file excerpt:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'register')) }}
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}
        {{ Form::text('email') }}

        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}

        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}

        {{ Form::submit('Sign Up')}}

      {{ Form::close() }}
```

When everything is saved and I try to register in the actual app, I get an error: the tutorial says it's because there is no default value set for the `remember_token` variable and suggests to go to phpMyAdmin to set the default value to NULL.

However, when I do so, I get the following error message:

[image: phpMyAdmin print screen]

Consequently, I cannot fix the error and proceed.

Any idea on how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin, you need to check the `Null` checkbox as well, to allow null values in this field.

It's barely cutoff on the right side of your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I just can see that the Null checkbox is not checked. Set the field as nullable by checking the Null checkbox as well.

Comment: Thanks Barry. This was actually the right move, as also suggested by helion3 above.